# How to break if a function is called from a certain file in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I have let's say 10 files file1,file2 ... file10 and each file has a function named fnCaller() which calls to a function say rmCaller(). I want to break only when this rmCaller() is called from fnCaller() in file4.Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [conditional breakpoints convenience functions](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html):

```
(gdb) break myAddress
Breakpoint 1 at <myAddress>
(gdb) cond 1 $_caller_is("myfunction1") && $_caller_is("myfunction2") ...
```

Comment: I want to specify the file also like i want to break when fnCaller is called from file4.c .

Comment: Like i had used convenience function already . It stopped for each file but i only want when file4.c calls it

Comment: I think you can create your own convenience function that does that. See the [implementation](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/python/lib/gdb/function/caller_is.py#l20) of `$_caller_is`, but instead of `frame.name()`, try `frame.find_sal().symtab.filename`.